# ModuleNotFoundError for a module that is installed and the path is in sys.path

Tags: python, pip, module, package

I implemented `from cubature import cubature`. However, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cubature._cubature'`.

I installed the package using `pip install cubature`. I also made sure that the path where the package is installed was added to `sys.path`. How can I fix the error?

Below is the exact error I get when implementing `import cubature`. I get a similar error when trying to use the package `vegas`.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      6 import scipy.optimize as so
      7 
----> 8 import cubature

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cubature\__init__.py in 
     39 __version__ = '0.17.2'
     40 
---> 41 from .cubature import *
     42 

~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cubature\cubature.py in 
      1 import numpy as np
      2 import ctypes
----> 3 from ._cubature import cubature as _cython_cubature
      4 from ._cubature import cubature_raw_callback as _cython_cubature_raw_callback
      5 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cubature._cubature'
```

Comment: Do you have a virtual environment ? What is the output of the command `pip freeze | grep cubature` ?

Comment: "I also made sure that the path where the package is installed was added to sys.path" How did you determine the path where it was installed? How did you add it to sys.path? What do you see in sys.path when you check it right before the import?

Comment: @rochard4u When I typed `pip freeze | grep cubature` in the terminal, I get `grep : The term 'grep' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I used the command `pip show cubature` to find the location where the `cubature` package was installed. I think I used the command `sys.path.append()` to add the location where the package was installed to `sys.path`. When I further typed `sys.path`, I saw the location of where the package was installed in the outputted list of locations.

Comment: @rochard4u I am  using Visual Studio Code on a Windows machine.